# if, else-if issue in R

Tags: r, if-statement

So I have been doing some project in which I am using multiple if-else-if conditions, the issue that I am facing is, whenever the first condition is met, the entire column is filled with that value itself, and it doesn't check further conditions.
This the code snippet that I am using :

```
rdw_acct_dedup$PROCESS <- if (substr(rdw_acct_dedup$STATUS_CD,1,1) == 'S') 
                      { 
                        rdw_acct_dedup$PROCESS <- '01)SOLD'
                      }else if(substr(rdw_acct_dedup$STATUS_CD,1,3) %in% c('894','895','910','994','D96','I25','I26','I27','Q34','V90','919','99F','99Q','D97','931','V22'))
                      {
                        rdw_acct_dedup$PROCESS <- '02)SIF-SETTLED'
                      }else if(substr(rdw_acct_dedup$STATUS_CD,1,3) %in% c('899','I45','PDV','U10','U39','V63'))
                      {
                        rdw_acct_dedup$PROCESS <-'03)SIF-PENDING'
                      }else if(substr(rdw_acct_dedup$STATUS_CD,1,1) == 'B') 
                      { 
                        rdw_acct_dedup$PROCESS <- '04)BANKRUPTCY'                                                                  
                      }else if(substr(rdw_acct_dedup$STATUS_CD,1,1) == 'V') 
                      { 
                        rdw_acct_dedup$PROCESS <- '05)PRE-BANKRUPTCY'
                      }else
                      {
                        rdw_acct_dedup$PROCESS <-'18)OTHER'
                      }
```

So even if the first condition is met entire process columns gets filled with '01)SOLD'

Comment: Can you provide a data example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick glance at how you could do it with nested `ifelse()`:

```
df <- data.frame(status = c("S104", "894T", "899X", "B67", "VXT", "ABC"))

  status
1   S104
2   894T
3   899X
4    B67
5    VXT
6    ABC

df$process <- with(df, ifelse(substr(status, 1, 1) == "S", "SOLD",
                              ifelse(substr(status, 1, 3) %in% c("894"), "SIF-SETTLED",
                                     ifelse(substr(status, 1, 3) %in% c("899"), "SIF-PENDING",
                                            ifelse(substr(status, 1, 1) == "B", "BANKRUPTCY",
                                                   ifelse(substr(status, 1, 1) == "V", "PRE-BANKRUPTCY", "OTHER"))))))

  status        process
1   S104           Sold
2   894T    SIF-SETTLED
3   899X    SIF-PENDING
4    B67     BANKRUPTCY
5    VXT PRE-BANKRUPTCY
6    ABC          OTHER
```

You'd need to include all the relevant numbers into the vectors for the `%in%` conditions, I was too lazy :)